# Copper powder from aqueous copper sulfate solution help

Tags: electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, electrolysis

I’ve been wanting to make copper powder for some homemade pyrotechnics. When placing an iron object in a copper sulfate solution, copper powder is produced. However, sooner or later, the reaction slows down and the solution begins to turn a teal color instead of its previous blue color. From what I’ve learned, the teal color is from iron sulfate. Therefore, the copper sulfate eventually gets used up.

I know another way to produce copper powder. Place two COPPER electrodes in the copper sulfate solution and the anode dissolves while copper powder builds up on the cathode. My question is, do I need to replace the copper sulfate solution if I do it this way? It seems I would not have to because the copper ions are being replaced by the dissolving anode.

Comment: Though the copper "sacrifial" electrode replaces that lost from solution, you may get solid copper plated out, rather than a fine powder.

Comment: I tested it today, and with my experimenting, a lower voltage(3-5) will result in plating and a higher voltage(12-24) will result in nice fluffy copper powder.

Comment: The net result of the 2 copper electrode scenario is moving copper from one electrode to another. If original copper is pure enough, you need not to replace the solution for  long time. Note that the key is not the applied voltage, but resulting current density.

Comment: In your first experiment, the copper sulfate eventually gets used up. But in your second experiment, the copper anode also gets used up. There is no miracle. Whatever your choice, there is an end to these experiments.

Comment: Right, but I’ve got loads of copper and not much sulfate. Granted, there are probably more efficient ways of producing copper powder.